# Hector: how to delete a composite colums inside a row

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have composite columns on the column family Tags

```
RowKey: A
=> (column=B:C, value=432b442b492b4b2b552b582b592b7465787433, timestamp=1338402672044003)
=> (column=C:D, value=442b492b4b2b552b582b592b7465787433, timestamp=1338402672044004)
=> (column=E:T, value=492b582b592b5a2b5a5a2b5a5a5a2b7465787434, timestamp=1338402672049002)
```

How could I delete in row A, column (C:D) for example

it seems:

```
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(ks, se);
mutator.addDeletion(..
```

takes only 2 arguments the row and the CF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people interested it's as easy as their creation;

```
CompositeSerializer ce = new CompositeSerializer();
Composite c = new Composite();
c.add(0, "John");
c.add(1, "Connor");
mutator.addDeletion("key", "MyCF", c, ce);
```